# What causes Error on browser "Aw Snap, status_access_violaiton"

Tags: google-chrome, browser, webserver, localhost, brave

i have a web server (svelte/next.js) running locally, but when i tried to access from any browser (edge,chrome,brave), it ran into a crash (see picture attached) 3-5 seconds after displayed and then returned an error "aw snap, status_acccess_violation". This only occured in the pc on which the server is running, it runs successfully from other locally connected pc

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRhIJ.png)

Comment: Typically fully update the errant server,

Answer (score 0):

i tried to undo some of the recent codes added in the project, it turned out that following css lines caused the problem:

.main-content{
height: calc(100% - 4em);
}

i still cannot understand why this would run the browser into crash in the server pc but not in other pc / locally connected client